# Нужно в список записать название песен на главной странице сайта, но не могу взять данные из всего, что под::before. Буду несказанно благодарен

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


titles = []

link = "https://www.jamendo.com/start"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'}

responce = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'lxml')

data = soup.find('div').find('div', id='skeleton-content-wrap')
```